# What are the consequences of immutable classes with references to mutable classes?

Tags: concurrency, immutability

I've recently begun adopting the best practice of designing my classes to be immutable per Effective Java [Bloch2008].  I have a series of interrelated questions about degrees of mutability and their consequences.

I have run into situations where a (Java) class I implemented is only "internally immutable" because it is immutable except that it uses (immutable) references to other mutable classes.  To clarify, if the object were constructed with its references set to immutable classes, the class would be immutable.

1. Do any of the benefits (see below) of immutable classes hold true even by only "internally immutable" classes?
2. Is there an accepted term for the
   aforementioned "internal mutability"?
   Wikipedia's [immutable object
   page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java) uses the unsourced term
   "deep immutability" to describe an
   object whose references are also
   immutable.
3. Is the distinction between mutability and
   side-effect-ness/state important?

---

The "Java Practices" site lists the following [benefits of immutable classes](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29):

- are simple to construct, test, and
  use
- are automatically thread-safe and
  have no synchronization issues
- do not need a copy constructor
- do not need an implementation of
  clone
- allow hashCode to use lazy
  initialization, and to cache its
  return value
- do not need to be copied defensively
  when used as a field
- make good Map keys and Set elements
  (these objects must not change state
  while in the collection)
- have their class invariant
  established once upon construction,
  and it never needs to be checked
  again
- always have "failure atomicity" (a
  term used by Joshua Bloch) : if an
  immutable object throws an exception,
  it's never left in an undesirable or
  indeterminate state

Answer (score 9):

A `Class` isn't truly **immutable** if any of this children references aren't **immutable** as well.
If your root `Class` has `final` references to all its instance variables and all those instance variables are **immutable** as well as all their children following this same **restriction** then you can say the root `Class` is **immutable**.

If any of the children references are non-`final` or any of the children instances are **mutable** then the containing `Class` is **not immutable**.

It doesn't matter about the *internal immutablity* whatever that means is anyone's guess, all that matters is that the public contract to the class **immutability** is kept. You can't have partial immutability anymore than you can be partially dead. Your class is either **immutable** or it isn't. And it isn't if any of its referred to classes or their classes, etc. are **mutable**.

If you have a graph and any of the members of the graph are **mutable** you can't deterministically say that you have an **immutable** state. Concurrency guarantees go out the window, `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` become non-deterministic and simple to test cloning and serializing go out the window as well.

**If anything breaks this immutability contract you lose all the benefits of trying to maintain this immutability contract.**

Simpler concurrency issues is a main motivational force of immutability.

Having side effect free code helps with predictability and maintainability. Since you don't have to wonder where things are getting mutated in the call tree because you know they can't be mutated.

Performance is another less important factor, in Java the JVM can make some highly optimized decisions about caching and other factors if it knows data can't change state. It does provide important hints to the compiler at compile time and the JIT algorithms at runtime.

Comment: Re: "*A Class isn't truly immutable if any of this children references aren't immutable as well*", I don't think that's quite true. It depends on the semantics of the class and how it actually *uses* the non-immutable object. It may be OK for an "immutable" `DocumentResultSet` to have references to mutable `Document` objects, as long as those references are `final`.

Comment: @glenviewjeff my answer addresses all the bullet points, there is no benefit to this mystical internally immutable class, the public contract of the class is all that matters.

Comment: This is a good answer, but why do you have to **bold** every single instance of **mutable** and **immutable**?  Really makes it harder to read.

Comment: @Darien I sort of agree. For example, I like to implement immutable lazy lists (handy for parsing) using an Iterator (the source), an ArrayList (elements that have been read from the source), and a position. In a sense the class is mutable because it references two mutable objects, but the mutability is completely encapsulated; the class fulfills the contract of an immutable structure.

Comment: please correct your answer to reflect the fact that an immutable object can reference mutable objects as long as: 1.  The references to its are not leaked; and 2. the immutable object cannot modify the mutable objects after construction.  (Java Concurrency in Practice, Section 3.4 Immutability, Goetz2006)

Comment: A class can hold references to mutable objects and still be considered immutable if the purpose of the references is to IDENTIFY rather than CONTAIN the objects referred to thereby.  For example, an immutable list of cars would be one that always refers to the same automobiles.  If the fifth car on the list is a red car with VIN #24601, it might tomorrow be a blue car with VIN #24601, but it won't have any other VIN#.

Comment: @supercat - agreed - in that case the references are just data being managed, not internal implementation details. In a sense it's like holding a collection of keys to database records that might mutate. However, some pure functional purists seem to deny that the idea of object/pointer identity makes any sense and insist that only value identity is valid. Of course they can't hold me responsible for this statement - by their own rule the me that I'll be by then will have mutated many times, so won't be the same person.

Comment: @Steve314 That all depends on the definition of “identity” being used. Value-identity + immutability is a nice combination (as it lets you be very aggressive about sharing instances) but it isn't the only workable one.

Comment: @DonalFellows: As I see it, any useful system must be mutable in at least one "layer", and it is easiest to reason about systems that are mutable in exactly one.  For example, there are three main ways to have a variable encapsulate a changeable sequence of integers: it may either hold an immutable reference to a mutable collection, a mutable reference to an immutable collection, or a mutable reference to a mutable collection.  The first two approaches are easier to reason about than the third, although encapsulating a variable-sized list in a framework where arrays are fixed size...

Comment: @DonalFellows: ...is often most practically done by holding a mutable reference to a mutable array [that is what `List<T>` does] although thread-safety is much harder when there are multiple mutable layers than when there is just one.  Code which needs to hold references to other objects is easiest if all mutation is confined to levels below the reference; code which deals with values is easiest if all mutation is confined to levels above.  It's too bad C# and VB don't provide much help with the reference-vs-value distinction; I suspect the right approach would often be...

Comment: @DonalFellows: ...to have parallel hierarchies of mutable and immutable types which share a common read-only interface, but that's apt to require a lot of code duplication.  I wish .NET languages had enforceable `readonly-ref` properties, and a means of exposing structures as `ref`, `readonly-ref`, and `const-ref` properties, since when working with mutable values the semantics of passing structures by `ref` are ideal (the recipient can use the reference but not persist it), and passing structures by `readonly-ref` or `const-ref` could be more performant than pass-by-value.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter as long as the class you say is immutable cannot be observed to be mutable.  E.g., memoisation uses mutation but a memoised value can be treated as immutable for all intents.

If I can't tell that your object uses mutable variables internally then it doesn't compromise my program and I can compose it with other objects as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Immutability is useful when designing concurrent applications because of the object state guarantees it provides. It's also quite useful for Sets and as Map keys... As far as i am concerned there's no choice between immutability and mutability. As an example, in a multithreaded Bank application, an Account object cannot be made immutable because its a dynamic entity which changes overtime and its unique to one holder. However a Discount or APR can be designed as an Immutable object because they do not vary beyond definition. In short your problem domain will decide how you model your objects. Too many times Java programmers write code for "Gang Of Four" as opposed to coding to customer's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the concept is reading the JLS and understanding it. In this case, the JLS says:

final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. A thread-safe immutable object is seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is used to pass references to the immutable object between threads. This can provide safety guarantees against misuse of an immutable class by incorrect or malicious code. final fields must be used correctly to provide a guarantee of immutability.

The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.
So you need to:

Make address both final and private.
Prevent any mutable reference to that object from being seen externally to your immutable object.
In this case, #2 probably means you can't return a reference to Address like you have with getAddress(). And you have to make a defensive copy. Make a copy of the object, and store that copy in Employee. If you can't make a defensive copy, there's really no way to make Employee immutable.

```
public final class Employee{
    private final int id;
    private final Address address;
    public Employee(int id, Address address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.address=new Address();  // defensive copy
        this.address.setStreet( address.getStreet() );
    }
    pulbic int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        Address nuAdd = new Address(); // must copy here too
        nuAdd.setStreet( address.getStreet() );
        return nuAdd;
}
```

Implementing clone() or something similar (a copy ctor) would make creating defensive objects easier for complicated classes. However, the best recommendation I think would be to make Address immutable. Once you do that you can freely pass around its reference without any thread-safety issues.

In this example, notice I do NOT have to copy the value of street.  Street is a String, and strings are immutable. If street consisted of mutable fields (integer street number for example) then I would have to make a copy of street also, and so on ad infinitum. This is why immutable objects are so valuable, they break the "infinite copy" chain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply put; *can your state change*?

This is not just through your objects API, but in every way an object can change state.

- You can't leak mutable references.
- You can't inject mutable references.
- You can't change state on any references, not even if the object is completely self contained.

You can initialize a mutable object, as long as no calls are ever made that change state, but you can still query it. So, if *internal mutability* is not what I described here, then no, you can't have that.